# How can I get NSFontManager selected font?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfontpanel, nsfontmanager

I can't get selected font in NSFontManager. What I need:

**1) I need to get selected font title, size, color?**

I am calling NSFontManager with button like this:

```
[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] orderFrontFontPanel:self];
```

It's opening but I don't know how to get selected font. **As string** for example: Verdana.

I have read apple's docs but I can't understand how to get what font is selected. I'm not changing or converting any fonts. I just need to get what font was selected.

Comment: Are you using the `-setTarget:`, `-setAction:`, and `-selectedFont` methods of NSFontManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *selectedFontName = [[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] selectedFont] displayName];
```

(depending on your intended use, you may want to use `fontName` instead of `displayName`.)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! now I can get font name. But how to get font's color?

Comment: The color has nothing to do with the font. Look at the documentation about `NSTextView`, `NSTextStorage` and `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: But at the top panel is "Text underline" "Text strikethrough" "Text color" this all is used for NSTextView yes? Thanks for information.